# JOIN query with IN operator

Tags: mysql, sql, join

A post have many comments,

I want to select only posts wich have comments with a certain id (ex: `(2, 4, 6, 7)`)

I tried the following sql query:

> SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts
>
> LEFT JOIN wp_comments ON wp_comments.comment_ID IN (2, 4, 6, 7);

The query return me weird results.

Can someone tell ma what wrong with this query ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.* 
FROM wp_posts AS P
INNER JOIN wp_comments AS C ON C.post_ID = P.post_ID
WHERE C.comment_ID IN (2, 4, 6, 7);
```

Modify the names of the columns for post_id in `ON C.post_ID = P.post_ID` as required; I'm not sure of the WordPress exact column names.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a `JOIN` condition, it should be in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if we could see your schema. I think your looking for something like this

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_comments ON wp_comments.postid = wp_posts.id
WHERE wp_comments.comment_ID IN (2, 4, 6, 7);
```

Comment: why a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `RIGHT JOIN`?